# How to show suggestions in Angular search bar?

Tags: angular, search

When I start searching in the search bar, automatically the search suggestions should also show ?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng2-filter-module.